# Token Generation Scheme Comparison

Tags: java, security, soap

We're in the process of defining a time-sensitive token generation scheme for our SOAP services.  Currently we have two ideas and we're not sure which is better and why.

### Scheme 1:

The rands at the beginning and end don't add any particular value, but the idea is to add a small layer of salting.

#### Sender

```
<token>rand(6) ++ encrypt(time) ++ rand(6)</token>
```

#### Receiver

```
enc = token.substring(6,token.len-6)
time = decrypt(enc)
assert(time is within +/- range)
```

### Scheme 2:

Here we encrypt the rands into the token.

#### Sender

```
<token>encrypt(rand(6) ++ encrypt(time) ++ rand(6))</token>
```

#### Receiver

```
dec = decrypt(token)
time = dec.substring(6,dec.len-6)
assert(time is within +/- range)
```

So I'm not only looking for an answer for which is best, but WHY it's best.  I've looked for some documents or best practices, but short of IEEE documents, I haven't found much.  If you have any documents you can point us to, we'd love that!

Comment: To what purpose are you generating these tokens ? To uniquely define a session ?

Comment: Missed this comment. We want to validate requesters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the two schemes you present, the first doesn't really address the goal of salting. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29):

> The primary function of salts is to defend against dictionary attacks
>   and pre-computed rainbow table attacks

and I would expect the salting to encrypt the same sequence differently each time you encrypt it. e.g. (using your examples)

```
  encrypt(rand(6) + encryptable)
```

such that multiple encryptions of the same sequence require individual decrypting.

If you need a unique token, rather than rely on a timestamp, why not use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) ?

Comment: We're looking for time-sensitive tokens.  GUIDs wouldn't give us that.  Unless I don't fully understand GUIDs.  I'll edit to state we need time-sensitivity.

Comment: We could do a GUID, but then we have to keep a list of valid GUIDs. We don't want to deal with that.  Moreover, we fine with new senders as long as they have our encryption key.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because the reminder on why we salt helped us decide.  We need to encrypt the rands because an attacker would attack the ciphertext since he would know a finite set of plaintext (the time range) to use in his attack.  Otherwise, they strip the rand and know exactly what plaintext they're looking for.